# Setting thesis margins

Tags: margins

My university requires theses to be bound and printed with the following specification:

```
There should be a margin of at least 1.5 inches, preferably 2 inches (5cm),   
on the left side of the page, 
both for typescript and diagrams, to allow for binding. Other margins should
be of at least 1 inch (2.5 cm).
```

If I plan to double-side print on `A4`, how can I ensure this in latex?
Would the following in the preamble suffice?

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{16mm} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{140mm}  
\setlength{\textheight}{200mm}  
\setlength{\topmargin}{8mm}
```

I found this in someone else's thesis. My understanding is that `oddsidemarin` sets the left margin for odd-numbered pages, minus 1 inch, so this gives 1 inch(25.5mm)+16mm: 1.63inches on the left side of the odd-numbered pages. Then `A4` dimensions are `210mm w x 297mm` so
`\setlength{\textwidth}{140mm}` along with my `oddsidemargin` means there will be `210-41.5-140=28.5mm=1.11inch` left for the right margin of odd-sided pages. Similarly, `\setlength{\textheight}{200mm}` means there is `297-200=97mm=3.8inches` left for both the top and bottom margins, so `1.9inches` each. Not sure what `\topmargin` is doing here.

Do I need to set `evensidemargin` too? Are the above settings correct to match the university specifications?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this in a sample document? That would in my opinion be the easiest way to see what they actually do. You can also find the different options for page layout [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: Did a few test prints, but it looks like the wider margin is not on the side of binding for the even pages...It doesn't look like `evensidemargin` would be the parameter to fix this as I think it sets the left-side even margins, whereas for the even pages the binding will be on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define inner and outer margins instead of left/right or even/odd and use the attributes of the documentclass to switch between oneside and twoside it will be all right. The example below works for me just fine.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}%

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newgeometry{
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    outer=1in,
    inner=2in,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to set `margin=1in` and additionally `bindingoffset=1in` for the page geometry.

Comment: @masu I tried this only with `\documentclass[twoside]{report}`, and the results don't seem quite correct. The even pages are good; I did a test print and the binding side margin is 2" and other side 1", great. However, the odd pages have binding side margin around 1.7" and other around 1.49" for some bizarre reason...

Comment: What about the output file? The output PDF is fine for me. If you have an all-right PDF (with the correct paper size !!) this is a printing problem, not TeX.

Comment: @masu No PDF bad too. However, your latex seems to work for me with the `lipsum` test, even when I use the `report` class, just not my thesis for some reason. It actually formats the first few pages correctly, but not the rest of the chapters. Could it be because I am using `\input` to compile multi `.tex` files or something?

Comment: Ah, sorry, problem found: I had some formatting commands hiding in one of the other input files that I had forgotten about. Seems to be working now.